# Google apps script global array not editable in function

Tags: arrays, function, google-apps-script, global, local

I wrote a small script in Google Apps Script that creates an array, and when you press a button it should add "test" to the array, and then print the whole array. So when you press the button for the first time it should display 1 "test". When you press it for the second time it should display the first test plus the new array which should contain 2 "test", so a total of 3 "test". But it doesn't. Somehow when it goes out of the function 'buttonPress' the whole array is deleted or something. Can someone explain this? Thanks!

```
 var list = new Array;
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication()
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('id')
  var button = app.createButton('Button')
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('buttonPress')
  button.addClickHandler(handler)
  app.add(panel)
  panel.add(button)
  return app;
}
function buttonPress(){
list.push('test')
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication()
var panel  = app.getElementById('id')
var panel2 = app.createVerticalPanel()
var length = list.length
for(var i = 0; i< length; i++){
panel2.add(app.createHTML(list[i]))
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

GAS isn't your everyday Javascript, everytime you hit the buttonPress, the whole code is compiled then executed, just by reading this you already figured, `list` gets re-instantiated as an empty array.

2 side notes:

UiApp has been deprecated, you must switch to HTMLService.

Arrays in Javascript are better initialized as `[]`. It's the prefered way in all documentations.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put your function `buttonPress()` does not know what `list` even is as you have not declared or defined it inside the function call.

If the code is the exact thing you are running I will note that `var list = new Array;` at the begging is not reachable by any of the functions.

If you wish, you can use `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('name',string)` and `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('name')` to store the array by using JSON.stringify() method and the JSON.parse() to get an array back.